# Exploding given IP range with the PHP

Tags: php, explode

i have a textarea:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<textarea name="test" rows="20" cols="20"></textarea>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

i want to type 195.2.2.13/16 and PHP should give me a list like that:

```
195.2.2.13
195.2.2.14
195.2.2.15
195.2.2.16
```

how can i do it with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that the code posted originally was fine for two decimal points but just incase you need to use 3 the below should work fine.

```
$input = "195.2.2.13/100";

function ipRange( $input ) {
    $input = explode( "/", $input );
        $numerator = substr( strrchr( $input[0], "." ), 1,  3 );
        $denominator = $input[1];
            $num = strlen( $numerator );
        $range = substr( $input[0], 0, -$num );

    while ( $numerator <= $denominator ) {
        echo $range.$numerator."<br />\n\r";
        $numerator++;
    }
}

// Call function
ipRange($input);
```

Comment: A++++++++, perfect. best of best. thank you very very much. it works very well. you are great. thanks

Comment: perfect, perfect. thank you very much. function is great too. it works so fine. A+++

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with [ip2long](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php).

Convert your string to an int, get the min and max IPs, iterate between them and render them back with [long2ip](http://php.net/manual/en/function.long2ip.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
$parts = explode('/', $_POST['name']);
$ip = $parts[0];
$max = $parts[1];
$octets = explode('.', $ip);
$start = $octets[3];

$ips = array();
for ($i = $start; $i <= $max; $i++) {
  if ($i > 254) {
    break;
  }

  $ips[] = $octets[0] . '.' . $octets[1] . '.' . $octets[2] . '.' . $i;
}
```